# Notification when uivuewcontroller gets popped

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app I push a viewcontroller on top of an other when a uitableviewcell gets selected. When I pop the new viewcontroller from top I get back to the one where I began with. 
When this happens I would like to perform a refresh action, but I don't know how to catch this event. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd use a delegate callback to notify the calling viewcontroller and perform the refresh in the callback method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BOOL pushed = [self isMovingToParentViewController];

    printf("viewWillAppear     %d\n", pushed);

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    BOOL popped = [self isMovingFromParentViewController];

    printf("viewWillDisappear     %d\n", popped);

}
```

from the Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Methods are available as of iOS5.0 
@Zoltan, what is your target version?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIViewController viewWillAppear delegate method